# Cannot enable USB mass storage (UMS) after changing internal SD card to emulated

Tags: usb, internal-storage, usb-connection-mode, mount

After I changed internal SD card to emulated (previous was on it's own
partition) I cannot enable USB mass storage of internal card.
I got inspired by section "Emulated primary only (like Nexus 4)" in
https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example.html.

I'm trying to figure out what to change in `vold.fstab` to be able to enable USB mass storage.

I'm working on Allwinner A31s, on Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean.

vold.fstab before my changes was (internal card was `/mnt/sdcard`):

```
dev_mount   sdcard  /mnt/sdcard auto    /devices/virtual/block/nandk
dev_mount   extsd   /mnt/extsd  auto    /devices/platform/sunxi-mmc.1/mmc_host  /devices/platform/sunxi-mmc.0/mmc_host
dev_mount   usbhost1    /mnt/usbhost1   auto    /devices/platform/sw-ehci.1 /devices/platform/sw_hcd_host0  /devices/platform/sw-ehci.2 /devices/platform/sw-ohci.1 /devices/platform/sw-ohci.2
```

I removed the first line (for `/mnt/sdcard`). I also tried to add line:

```
dev_mount   sdcard  /mnt/shell/emulated     auto    /devices/platform/sw-ehci.1 /devices/platform/sw_hcd_host0  /devices/platform/sw-ehci.2 /devices/platform/sw-ohci.1 /devices/platform/sw-ohci.2
```

but it didn't help.
I suppose it needs to be entry in `vold.fstab` for emulated devices as well. How to find correct `sysfs_path`?

I also changed attribute `android:emulated` to `true` in `storage_list.xml`.

UPDATE: The change in partition layout was to remove partition for internal SD card (`/mnt/sdcard`) and resize `/data` partition – add this free space to it. Internal SD card is mounted into `/data` partition (as `/mnt/shell/emulated` in `/data/media`).

It's done with `sdcard` service (defined in rc script):

```
service sdcard /system/bin/sdcard /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated 1023 1023
    class late_start
```

I have probably some misconfiguration in `storage_list.xml` as `UsbStorageActivity` is shown, but after clicking to enable button does not finish enabling. But this is a minor problem, the main issue is the inability to set UMS.

When I watch `vold` with `vdc   monitor` it does nothing, prior to previous version when it worked as   expected - unmounting device and changing it's state). This happens also if  there is also external SD card presented.

Debugging with `logcat` shows that in case of emulated SD card:

- PackageManager is not called
- Vold is not called
- MediaScannerReceiver is not called
- MountService (runned in thread by UsbStorageActivity) skips both   internal  and partition (doesn't umount either of them) and progress indicator keeps running.

Comment: You can't. UMS only works on complete partitions, which are "physically handed-out". So if I understood your question correctly, and your "emulated card" now is just "a subdirectory of some other storage" (and no longer a separate partition – your question is lacking those details), AFAIK there's no way to use it with UMS.

Comment: @izzy: Thanks for info. Could you provide link to documentation? Is it version dependent, or is it valid for all android versions (>= Jelly Bean)? What surprises me is that Nexus 4 (`mako`) should have internal card emulated (not on physical device) and it's possible to share it to computer (as `MTP` or `PTP`) &ndash; see <a href="https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_lge_mako/blob/cm-10.1/init.mako.rc#L399">init.mako.rc for Jelly Bean</a>. The main purpose is to connect internal storage _anyhow_ to computer.

Comment: All depends on setup. The "emulated" variant is using FUSE. You can of course set this on top of a "full partition" (which might be the case with the N4), and then of course can make that available via UMS as well. Doesn't depend on Android version, but rather on whether the underlying "card" is on a separate partition or not. But no, I have no link to documentation – just "general knowledge" :)